# How to use the TortoiseSVN Filter button in the Revision Graph?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

The Tortoise SVN Filter button doesn't do anything. No matter what you enter into the dialog box nothing gets filtered out.

I am using Tortoise SVN version 1.14.5's revision graph that has a button to filter by revision ranges or filter out paths that contain certain strings but when I try either and click OK nothing happens. I was expecting it to hide nodes in the revision graph based on what I entered in the dialog box based on the documentation here: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html#tsvn-dug-revgraph-dia-1